# ¿Como acceder a las variables de una función(A) desde una función(B) contenida en (A), en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> En JavaScript las funciones funcionan como cajas negras donde se
>   almacenan las variables, el objeto global no puede acceder a estas,
>   pero desde el interior de la funcion podemos acceder a los elementos
>   exteriores.

Al usar `this` nos referimos al ámbito que llama a esa variable.

Si declaramos una variable de la siguiente manera:

```
this.x = "soy x";
```

Podremos acceder de la siguiente manera:

```
window.x;
```

Esto porque fue declarada dentro del ambito del `window`.

---

En el caso de las funciones, si empleamos `this` en el siguiente codigo, podremos acceder a la variable declarada en el primer momento (en `window` fuera de la función), esto debido a que el dueño o el encargado de llamar a la función fue `window`:

```
var ejemplo = "Estoy en window";
function mostrar() {
  var ejemplo = "Estoy en funcion";
  console.log(this.ejemplo)
}
mostrar();
// Resultado: "Estoy en window";
```

---

Mi pregunta viene con referencia a este siguiente codigo:

```
var ejemplo = "Estoy en window";
function mostrar1() {
  var ejemplo = "Estoy en mostrar1";
  function mostrar2() {
    var ejemplo = "Estoy en mostrar2"
      console.log("Funcion scope: "+ejemplo+"Window Scope: "+this.ejemplo);
  }
mostrar2();
}
mostrar1();
// Resultado "Funcion scope: Estoy en mostrar2 Window Scope Estoy en Window"
```

---

¿De que manera lograr que la funcion `mostrar2()` acceda al valor contenido en la funcion `mostrar1()`?.

Es decir lograr el siguiente mensaje:

```
// Resultado "Funcion scope: Estoy en mostrar2 Window Scope Estoy en mostrar1"
```

---

Ya que, observo que accede a la variable `ejemplo` en `window`, porque el encargado de llamar a `mostrar1()` fue `window`.

¿Pero no es acaso `mostrar1()` quien llamada a `mostrar2()`?.

¿No debería convertirse `mostrar1()` en el `this` de la función `mostrar2(`)?, puesto fue el quien la invoco.

---

Intente aplicando el siguiente método:

```
var ejemplo = "Estoy en window";
function mostrar1() {
  var ejemplo = "Estoy en mostrar1";
  var self = this;
  function mostrar2() {
    var ejemplo = "Estoy en mostrar2"
      console.log("Funcion scope: "+ejemplo+"Window Scope: "+self.ejemplo);
  }
mostrar2();
}
mostrar1();
// Resultado "Funcion scope: Estoy en mostrar2 Window Scope Estoy en Window"
```

Tratando de recordar que `mostrar1()` era el ambito de ejecucion de `mostrar2()` pero sigue mostrando el mismo resultado

Comment: En lo particular; será de utilidad coloques el escenario que tienes y lo que has probado; me parece un planteamiento más de curiosidad que un problema que tengas para el desarrollo de tu sistema/aplicación web.

Comment: Es un planteamiento de curiosidad, pero podría ocurrir en la aplicación, y quisiera entender como acceder a ese elemento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que hace la palabra `this` básicamente es preguntar: **¿La propiedad en la que estoy parado actualmente, a qué objeto pertenece?**

---

Cuando defines una variable de la forma:

```
this.x = 3;
var y = 5;
```

El ámbito de esas variables es el objeto `window` exactamente como dijiste. Pero la palabra **ámbito**, se refiere a que tanto `x` como `y` ahora son *propiedades* del objeto `window`.

Si haces:

```
function mostrar() { ... }
```

En este caso es bastante similar a hacer algo como:

```
window.mostrar = function() { ... }
```

También pasan a formar parte de (se convierten en una propiedad de) `window`.

---

Ahora, qué pasa cuando decides hacer algo como:

```
function mostrar() {
  var x = 3;
  function mostrar2() { ... }
}
```

¿Alguna vez accediste a una variable local del cuerpo de una función (*mostrar*) como `mostrar.x` para obtener de resultado un 3? Así como no puedes hacer eso para conseguir un 3, sucede lo mismo con mostrar2. Por lo tanto: mostrar2 no es una propiedad de mostrar.

Todo lo que pongas dentro del cuerpo de una función, es considerado como un bloque de código a ejecutar, un **closure**. No como un conjunto de propiedades dentro de ese objeto.

Ahora, si quieres por ejemplo; desde **mostrar2** acceder al contenido de **mostrar1**, simplemente puedes hacerlo así:

```
function mostrar1() {
  var variableDeMostrar1 = 3;
  function mostrar2() {
    console.log(variableDeMostrar1); // => 3;
  }
  mostrar2();
}
```

Entonces:

```
mostrar1(); // => 3;
```

---

Por otra parte, si quisieras cambiar el contenido de la referencia `this`, lo que tienes que hacer es crear una propiedad dentro del objeto que quieres que devuelva la palabra `this`. Ya que el ámbito de una propiedad, es el objeto al que pertenece esa propiedad. Por lo tanto:

```
var algo = {
  mostrar: function() {
    console.log(this); // => Ahora es el objeto en algo.
  }
}
```

Entonces:

```
algo.mostrar(); // => Object {mostrar: function}
window.algo.mostrar(); // => Object {mostrar: function}
```

Tiene sentido que devuelva eso, porque *mostrar* es ahora propiedad del objeto al que hace referencia `algo`.

Vale notar que dentro de un objeto, ya no se puede usar la sintaxis de:

```
var x = 3;
function mostrar() { ... }
```

Sino que directamente hay que usar la notación de propiedades en objetos:

```
{
  propiedad1: 3, 
  propiedad2: 5
}
```

Por lo que a mi entender, lo que querías entender se llama **Closure**. Y lo confundías con algo como esto:

```
var miObjeto = { 
  mostrar: function() { 
    console.log(this);
    return ({ 
      mostrar2: function() {
        console.log(this);
      }
    }).mostrar2(); 
  }
}
```

En esta forma:
 - `mostrar` es una propiedad de `miObjeto`.
 - `miObjeto` es una propiedad de `window`. 
 - `mostrar` como propiedad hace referencia a una función. La palabra `this` dentro de ella hace referencia al objeto a `miObjeto` ya que `mostrar` es propiedad de él.
 - Puedes hacer que `mostrar` te devuelva otro objeto. Si a ese otro objeto también le agregas una propiedad; y en esa propiedad haces referencia a una nueva función; la palabra `this` va a preguntar a qué objeto pertenece esa propiedad. Por lo tanto `this` hará referencia a ese nuevo objeto anónimo.

Quedando tu cadena de objetos:

```
window{} => miObjeto{ mostrar: function } => { mostrar2: function }
```

Comment: Sí, las variables de la función más interna terminan pisando a las del contexto superior. Eso si hay que cuidar un poco.

Comment: Mas información sobre closures en stackoverflow en inglés. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 1):

**Conflicto de Ámbito y Conflicto de Nombre**:

> Para complementar la respuestas de @francute, agregare lo que se
>   conoce como **scope conflict** ó **conflicto del ámbito** y **name conflict** ó **conflicto de nombre**.

**Conflicto de Ámbito**:

> *Este se refiere a romper la conexión entre una variable y el ambito que podia acceder a ella, esto ocurre generalmente al colocar una variable dentro de una función*.

Veamos, si tenemos el siguiente código:

**Ejemplo 1**:

```
var a = 1;
function foo() {
    var b = 2;
    console.log(b);
}
foo();
// 2
b;
// undefined
```

Al llamar a `foo()` romperé la conexión entre el **scope** `window` y el **scope** de la función ya que desde `window` no podre acceder a la `variable b` que esta dentro de `foo()`.

---

**Solucion al conflicto de ambito**:

> Si quisiera acceder a la `variable a` desde `foo()` debo agregar explicita-mente la ruta o el ambito desde donde es declarada dicha variable, en este caso `window` o `this`.

**Ejemplo 2**:

```
 var a = 1;
      function foo() {
        var b = 2;
        console.log(window.a);
        }
 foo();
 // 1
```

---

**Conflicto de Nombre**:

> *Ocurre cuando declaro dos variables con el mismo nombre refiriéndose a dos valores
>   distintos*.

**Ejemplo 3**:

```
var a = 1;
  function foo() {
    var a = 2;
    console.log(a);
  }
foo(); 
// 2
a;
// 1
```

Al ocurrir este tipo de conflicto debo observer detenidamente como funcion el *acceso a variables en JavaScript*.

---

**Acceso a variables en JavaScript**:

> *Al llamar variables JavaScript utiliza las que se encuentren mas
>   cercanas a la función que los llamo*.

Es decir que en el caso anterior (**Ejemplo 3**) se obtendrá:

```
// 2
```

Por ser esa `variable a` la mas cercana a `bar()`.

Si quisiera obtener el valor de la `variable a` que esta afuera debería usar `this`:

**Ejemplo 4**:

```
var a = 1;
  function foo() {
    var a = 2;
    console.log(this.a);
    }
foo();
// 1
```

Pero ahora vamos a complicar el planteamiento.

---

**Problemática en la pregunta**:

> Ahora bien, ¿que pasa si deseo agregar otra función dentro de la
>   principal para acceder a sus variable?, de esta manera:

**Ejemplo 5:**

```
var a = 1;
  function foo() {
    var a = 2;
    function bar() {
      var a = 3;
      console.log(a);
    }
    bar();
  }
foo();
// 3
```

¿Que se puede hacer para acceder a la `variable a con valor(2)` desde la función `bar()`?:

Según los planteamientos anteriores podria accionar tal como si se tratara del **Ejemplo 2**, agregaría la ruta de donde proviene el llamamiento:

**Ejemplo 6**:

```
var a = 1;
  function foo() {
    var a = 2;
    function bar() {
      var a = 3;
      console.log(this.a);
    }
    bar();
  }
foo();
// 1
```

Pero si este es el caso, ¿por que el resultado es: 1 (variable a con valor(1)) y no la `variable a con valor(2)`?.

Esto ocurre porque tenemos ambos conflictos: **Ambito y Nombre**.

---

**Conflicto de Ambito y Acceso a Variables**:

> Para dar respuesta tomare tres elementos:

1) ¿Quien es `this` en este planteamiento?:

`window` llama a `foo()`
`foo()` a `bar()`
`bar()` muestra a `a`.

`this` es por lo tanto: `window`

2) Intervension del **clousure** (*Respuesta de @francute*):

JavaScript al ver que estamos llamando a la `variable a con valor(2)` en el `console.log()` que posee `bar()` recordara en la memoria dicha variable y su valor para ser llamado cuando lo necesite, *una referencia*.

3) En tercer lugar recordemos que:

> al llamar variables JavaScript utiliza las que se encuentren mas 
>   cercanas a la función que los llamo.

Por la tanto, por mas que JavaScript recuerde a la `variable a con valor(2)` como parte de la función `bar()`, La función `bar()` conseguirá primero a la `variable a con valor(3)` dentro de ella, en vez de la `variable a con valor(2)`, y como la `variable a con valor(1)` le pertenece a `window` no podremos usar `this.a`.

---

**Solucion del Problema**:

Repararemos el **conflicto de Nombre**, cambiando el nombre de la `variable a con valor(3)` para poder acceder correctamente al **closure** que JavaScript creo para la `variable a con valor(2)`:

**Ejemplo 7**:

```
var a = 1;
  function foo() {
    var a = 2;
    function bar() {
      var c = 3;
      console.log(a);
    }
    bar();
  }
foo();
// 2
```